# Create Libraries and Permissions with SharePoint Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to make a script to help automate this process a bit but am fairly new to using PowerShell with SharePoint and don't really know the route to take.

I have a list of 40 items and I need to make a library for each one. Each library then needs to have unique permissions with 3 default groups(Owners, Members, Visitors). The groups should be named the same as the List.Title + Owners/Members/Visitors.

So far I create a site group as follows:

```
# Owner Group
$web.SiteGroups.Add(“$web Owners”, $web.Site.Owner, $web.Site.Owner, “Use this group to     grant people full control permissions to the $web site”)
$ownerGroup = $web.SiteGroups["$web Owners"]
$ownerGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = $true
$ownerGroup.Update()
```

The naming of my groups needs to be the list title and not the web name as I have above.

I create a new library like this:

```
PS > $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://SPServer 
PS > $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary 
PS > $spWeb.Lists.Add("My Documents","My Doc Library",$listTemplate)
```

Clearly this is not automated at all and no faster than just using the GUI to make each new library and adding in the site groups. Can anyone help get me started on a script that would iterate through a list of names create a library and create 3 groups on the site for each new library?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does the object containing the 40 list items look like?

Comment: It's in a SQL database as well as just a list in an excel document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on the right track I believe.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$Lists = @("My Documents", "My Docs", "Testing")
$Groups = @("Owners", "Members", "Visitors")
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary

$Web = Get-SPWeb "Your_URL"

$Lists | ForEach-Object {
    $ListName = $_
    $Description = "$_ Description"
    $Web.Lists.Add($ListName, $Description, $listTemplate)
    $Groups | % {
        $GroupName = "$ListName $_"
        $Web.SiteGroups.Add($GroupName, $Web.Site.Owner, $Web.Site.Owner, "Group $GroupName created by automatic process")
        $group = $Web.SiteGroups["$GroupName"]
        if ( !$GroupName -contains "Visitors")
        {
            $group.AllowMembersEditMembership = $true
        } else
        {
            $group.AllowMembersEditMembership = $false
        }
        $group.Update()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will dig into this today!

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, and good luck.  Please note, you will need to match your Lists/Groups objects to what you are getting from SQL and Excel.  This is really persuade code.

Comment: I used $lists = import-csv "path to file" to get the list for the names of each library. Is this an okay way of doing that as well?

I was also wondering on the following part:

    $Description = "$_ Description"
What is the variable getting from $_ Description? Is it possible to set a variable for description that would grab text from a csv as well for the description?

Comment: I had to fake my way with the description since I did not have a source.  You should use import-csv where each row has the list name and description.  Then iterate over each row and use those values to provide the relevant variables.  You are well on your way.

Comment: I think I got it working quite well, much thanks to websch01ar!

I imported my csv for the $lists which had 2 columns name and description. I then set $listname to name and $description to description from the csv.

If I wanted each list to be added to quicklaunch as well would this work in the foreach block: $list = $web.lists["$listname"] then $list.onquicklaunch=true?

Comment: According to the MSDN page on the OnQuickLaunch property, it does support setting this value, so I believe that would work.  Good work Braden.

Comment: I was modifying the script I made from your advice and am trying to figure out what the ! before $GroupName in your if statement does. Is it grabbing the current $GroupName variable?

Comment: ! = Not in logic operators.  Sorry for the delay in responding.